# How handle Entity Framework navigation property CollectionChanged event?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Let's say I have Entity like this:

```
public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Node Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

    public Node()
    {
        Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
        Nodes.CollectionChanged += Nodes_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Nodes_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something just if the USER adds or romoves item.
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `Nodes_CollectionChanged` function is also called when `EF` initializes the property for the first use, and not only when the user adds or romoves an item.

My question is how can I respond only when the user adds or removes an item from the list?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle [ObjectMaterialized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized(v=vs.110).aspx) event, when EF added all items to collections and call some method, where you can subscribe:

```
public Context() 
{
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized +=
          (sender, e) => Subscribe(e.Entity as Node);

}
public void Subscribe(Node node)
{
    node?.Subscribe();
}

public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Node Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

    public Node()
    {
        Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        Nodes.CollectionChanged += Nodes_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Nodes_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something just if the USER adds or romoves item.
    }
}
```

Comment: `ObjectMaterialized` occurs before the `Nodes` fills up. `Nodes` fills up in the first use. how can I know that `Nodes` already full?

Comment: @magicode yes, I checked - event fired after one element of child collection was added, it's strange. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problem completely I would recommend to use entities only as data transport objects. Implement your business logic separately and your are free to do anything you want to. A `NodeModel` can handle your collection changes and you can control its lifecycle. Just use the `Node` entity to load / save the data.